# How to add and render a region in omega 3.x subtheme?

Tags: theming

Can anyone let me know as how to render a region in omega 3.x subtheme ?

I have tried creating a region using this command in .info file as  regions[region name] = region name and used render command in page--front.tpl.php  , ,but regions are not getting rendered !

Can anyone please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the cache first.

Go to the subtheme appearance settings, click the "Zone and region configuration" tab, and scroll down to the bottom to find your "unassigned regions". Simply assign it to a zone, configure the options above, and save.

Go to Structure and check "Demonstrate block regions".

Comment: @Niji nice to here you, enjoy :)